# How to find user datas in cakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i just startet to play with CakePHP3 and create a simple Authentication.

I create a simple Authentication with username & wassword.

In my view I want to show user details from my "User" table.

I want to find ID and USERNAME:

```
$username =  $this->Auth->user('id');
$userid   =  $this->Auth->user('username');
```

I get the correct Informations. 
But when I want find the other informations I don't get any Result:

```
$userrole =  $this->Auth->user('role');
```

He alway find nothing (NULL).

How can I find the "User role"? Must I create an query to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthComponent::user($key = null)`

The `user()` function returns any **column** from the currently logged in user:

```
// From inside a controller or other component.
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

If the current user is not logged in or the key doesn’t exist, `null` will be returned.

See also:

- [Accessing the Logged In User](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)

Comment: but why my key is empty? id username email he find. Role not

Comment: i use the default user model from cake with his default table.